# IR2112 give out bad wave

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving

I have connected an IR2112 as a low side gate driver in Proteus.

Its output is very bad (blue graph.) It is even worse at higher frequency (given is 7812 Hz.)

[image]

Is this how the IR2112 supposed to behave?

Here is the schematic:

[image]

SD, COM and VS connected to ground. VC is 19V, LIN in shown in first picture (green graph.)

Comment: Show the connection to the load/MOSFET please. A tiny snippet of part of a schematic is not sufficient.

Comment: It looks like normal response with a quantization error in simulation

Comment: It doesn't seem *so* bad to me. It's a chunky gate driver after all (newer one are way more reliable)

Comment: That depends what it's driving, which we know nothing about.

Comment: How is that bad? That looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's driving a big MOSFET (or several MOSFETs in parallel) with a lot of gate charge (hundreds of nC) and a Vt around 5V.

This kind of gate driver can source/sink a few hundred mA. You can get beefier ones that can source or sink many amperes.

Comment: thank you. gate driver was way too weak. I added a few more in parallel